# GROUP BY id HAVING value like 'X' or value like 'Y'

Tags: postgresql, group-by, having

Table `bo_sip_cti_event_day` has columns: `uuid, hangup_clause` but I have many the same `uuid` in many records with other `hangup_clause` for example: `a, ORIGINATOR_CANCEL`, `a, NO_ANSWER`, `a, ALLOTTED_TIMEOUT`.

I have to get all `uuid` where hangup_cause is `ORIGINATOR_CANCEL` and `NO_ANSWER` for the same `uuid`.

So far I tried:
`select uuid from bo_sip_cti_event_day group by uuid having hangup_cause like 'ORIGINATOR_CANCEL' and hangup_cause like 'NO_ANSWER'`
but then the error says that `hangup_cause` have to be in group by clause or be in aggregation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `HAVING` clause you deal with aggregates. Conditional aggregates in your case:

```
select uuid
from bo_sip_cti_event_day 
group by uuid
having count(case when hangup_cause = 'ORIGINATOR_CANCEL' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when hangup_cause = 'NO_ANSWER' then 1 end) > 0;
```

This gives you all UUID for which both hangup clauses exist.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot the `CASE` keyword. Please try again.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks